# element reference inside accumulate method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

could someone help me understand what the s[1] and s[0] are referring to in the code below? This code will generate a Fibonacci serie. And I am still trying to understand how accumulate() works. Does it return the first value (0,1) as it is, then uses the result from the first application of the lambda function as s[1] and another tuple (0,1) from the list generated by repeat() as s[0]? or s[0] and s[1] are assigned as 0 and 1 respectively?

Thanks!

```
import itertools as it
def second_order(p, q, r, initial_values):
    """Return sequence defined by s(n) = p * s(n-1) + q * s(n-2) + r."""
    intermediate = it.accumulate(
        it.repeat(initial_values),
        lambda s, i: (s[1], p*s[1] + q*s[0] + r)
    )
    return intermediate
fibs = second_order(p=1, q=1, r=0, initial_values=(0, 1))
list(next(fibs) for n in range(8))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexable[n]` is the way to get the value in index `n` of `indexable`. Since tuples are indexable collections (they define `__getitem__`), you're getting the zero-index and one-index of that tuple (the first and second values, respectively).

This might be better-understood in the no-longer-valid syntax:

```
lambda (s1, s2), i: (s2, p*s2 + q*s1 + r)
```

---

As you correctly intuited, `accumulate([x1, x2, x3], fn)` returns the infinite series `[x1, fn(x1, x2), fn(x2, fn(x1, x2)), ...]`  `fn` in this case is a function that has the signature:

```
def fn(last_last_value, last_value)
```

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20accumulate#itertools.accumulate) probably show this most clearly, using `operator.add` (aka `+`)

```
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], operator.mul) --> 1 2 6 24 120
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        total = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `p=1` and `q=1` and `r=0`, we can ignore them altogether and it ultimately boils down to just this:

```
it.accumulate( 
    [(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1), ...], 
    lambda prev, current: (prev[1], prev[1] + prev[0])
)
```

You can visualize it like this:

```
0th:                             -> result0= (0,1)
1th: prev=(0,1)    current=(0,1) -> result1= (1, 0+1)= (1,1)
2nd: prev=result1  current=(0,1) -> result2= (0+1, 0+1+1)= (1,2)
3rd: prev=result2  current=(0,1) -> result3= (0+1+1, 0+1+1+0+1)= (2,3)
4th: prev=result3  current=(0,1) -> result4= (0+1+1+0+1, 0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1)= (3,5)
...
```

as you can see `current` never gets used. 
In your code `i` is `current`, `s` is `prev`, and so `s[0] == prev[0]` which is the first element in the tuple, and `s[1]` is the 2nd element